# How to compare and join two dataframes based on the list in another dataframe

Tags: r

I have 3 files

```
F1 - par, ch
F2 - ch
F3 - par
```

So for the par, ch pair in F1, I want to retrieve values from F2 and F3. Then paste row values of par to ch on left.

For example

If par is `s` & chi is `9t` ===> result : s9t

```
s apply(row_values(tab),function(name){ paste(name, tab[,name])})
```

File 1: Containing list Par, ch

```
F1 <- structure(list(par = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), ch = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L,  4L, 5L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

File 2: Containing ch

```
F2 <- structure(list(ch = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "factor"), c1 = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("9n", "9NA", "9s", "9t"), class = "factor"), c2 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("11f", "11p", "11t", "11x", "11z"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

File 3: Containing par

```
F3 <- structure(list(par = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), class = "factor"), c1 = structure(c(4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("c", "n", "r", "s", "t"), class = "factor"), c2 = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("e", "r", "s", "t"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

result --> paste row values of par to row values of ch on left (for the par, ch pair in F1)

```
result <- structure(list(ch = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), class = "factor"), c1 = structure(c(4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("c9n", "n9t", "r9s", "s9s", "t9NA"), class = "factor"), c2 = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("e11f", "r11t", "s11x", "t11p", "t11z"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description does not seem to be consistent with `result` as there are multiple matches but assuming we should output every one:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.*, c.c1 || b.c1 as c1, c.c2 || b.c2 as c2
  from F1 a
  join F2 b using(ch)
  join F3 c using(par)")
```

giving:

```
  par ch   c1   c2
1   a  b  s9s t11p
2   b  c t9NA r11t
3   c  a  n9s s11f
4   c  a  r9s e11f
5   c  d  n9t s11x
6   c  d  r9t e11x
7   d  e  c9n t11z
```

or equivalently giving the same result:

```
n <- 2
cStrings <- toString(sprintf("c.c%d || b.c%d as c%d", 1:n, 1:n, 1:n))
fn$sqldf("select a.*, $cStrings
  from F1 a
  join F2 b using(ch)
  join F3 c using(par)")
```

Add `verbose = TRUE` to the `sqldf` call to see the actual SQL statement passed to SQLite.

Comment: Hello Grothendieck,
Thank you very much! Yes, I forgot the multiple matches sorry.
I have multiple columns, could you please let me know how to iterate to all columns.

Comment: sorry I mean i have c1 to c54 - 54 columns that needs to be matched.

Comment: Thank you very much